# How to connect to database, edit data and show them on listview in WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mvvm

I am creating application like task manager. I have my task saved in database and I want to show them in my apllication and add some new.

How to connect to db and bind data to observable collection to show them in listView? And how can I would add new record to database?

I have this.

[image: app]

Adding to observable collection works properly.

Code:

```
public TheTaskViewModel()
        {
            // Initial task with default values
            Task = new TheTask
            {
                Id = 0,
                Priority = Priority.Normal,
                Status = Status.New
            };

            // Observable collection of tasks to notify UI
            Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TheTask>();
        }

private void SubmitExecute(object parameter)
        {
            Tasks.Add(Task);
        }
```

xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" Width="Auto" Margin="0,175,0,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Priorytet" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Priority}" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Termin" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Term}" Width="80"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Treść" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Content}" Width="Auto"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Write code to retrieve rows from the database and create corresponding instances of `TheTask`. Are you using entity framework, or just SQL? If it's EF, TheTask should be an EF entity class. If not EF, you'll need to use SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc. to retrieve the rows, and you'll need to do something to save them back to the database.